# Dual subgradient method - no analytical relation between primal and dual variables.

Tags: convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, duality-theorems, subgradient

Consider the a convex optimization problem to minimize $f(x)$ subject to the constraint $g(x)\leq0$. Based on the lecture notes [Link,Pg 23](http://www1.se.cuhk.edu.hk/~sqma/SEEM5121_Spring2015/subgrad_method_notes.pdf) , the Lagrange can be expressed as
$$L(x,\lambda) = f(x) + \lambda g(x)$$
Suppose $x(\lambda)$ is the minimizer for $\min_x L(x,\lambda)$ ($x(\lambda)$ denotes $x$ in terms of $\lambda$ and this expression is generally obtained by KKT conditions), then the subgradient method to update dual variable $\lambda$ and find optimal dual variable $\lambda^*$ is given by

- Initialize $\lambda(0)$
- for $i$
- $x(i) = x(\lambda(i))$
- $\lambda(i+1) = [\lambda(i) + \alpha_i g(x(i))]_+$
- end $i$

where $\alpha_i$ is the step size and $[\cdot]_+=max(\cdot,0)$.

My question is in some cases, it is hard or impossible to find $x(\lambda)$, i.e., no analytical expression for $x(\lambda)$ (This happens a lot when you have multiple nonlinear constraints). In these cases, how does subgradient method work to find the optimal dual $\lambda^*$. If subgradient method fails, any other efficient method to find $\lambda^*$. Any suggestion or reference is appreciated.

Comment: What's your optimization problem? You could just use a primal-dual method that solves the primal and dual problems simultaneously.

Comment: @littleO My optimization problem is too complicated to mention here. is the primal-dual subgradient method (section 8 in my link) the one you refer to? Any more detailed reference for it?

Comment: My student just wrote a paper on this problem that may be of interest here, it has faster convergence than standard primal-dual subgradient: http://ee.usc.edu/stochastic-nets/docs/primaldual-convex-cdc2016.pdf

Comment: @Michael that looks very interesting. Seems to be inspired by the concepts of accelerated gradients (Nesterov)?

Comment: Two very versatile primal-dual algorithms that I use a lot are the Chambolle-Pock algorithm and ADMM. I'd guess that either of those algorithms or the one mentioned by Michael might be useful to you, but I'd have to look at the optimization problem to know for sure.

Comment: @MichaelGrant Like Nesterov, our algorithm uses decisions at time $t-1$.  However, this seems to be a coincidence and we do not know if there is a deeper relationship.  It was inspired by Lyapunov drift, where a pesky $g(x(t))^2$ term slows convergence.  We could remove this term by doing a minimization of the form $min_{x \in \mathcal{X}}[f(x) + \lambda g(x) + a g(x(t))^2]$ every step, but $g(x(t))$ is usually a sum of terms and squaring it would make these terms appear nonseparably.   So we approximated it by $g(x(t))g(x(t-1))$, then we compensate for the error using a prox term.

Comment: @littleO A simple example of my problem is shown here https://www.dropbox.com/s/dnlghrri5efu44l/example.pdf?dl=0                             The only problem might be the logrithm. Some solvers like CVX can definitely solve this as well as the dual, but I want to get some insights about how dual variables are obtained. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. That's an interesting problem because you have perspective functions everywhere. I guess it's not so clear how to apply the proximal algorithms I mentioned, and maybe the problem is small enough that interior point methods are a better choice anyway.

Comment: Maybe one possibility if there is no analytical formula for $x(\lambda)$ when using the dual subgradient method would be to solve for $x(\lambda)$ using Newton's method. Newton's method might converge very quickly because you have a good first guess from the previous iteration. (But, I would be inclined to just not use the dual subgradient method.)